# resize canvas to its parent element ion-grid

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, flexbox, ionic3

I am building a component in Ionic 3 that put a grid of images and connects them with a canvas overlay. I've used Ionic's `ion-grid` but when I try to resize the canvas I cannot find the correct dimensions of the container so the canvas container remains to its initial size. I would like to make it dynamic so I need the canvas to have the same size as the grid container. Here's my code:

```
    <ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <div ion-card-content>

        <div ion-grid id= "container-graph">
           <ion-row responsive-sm>
            <canvas id="connection-canvas" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row responsive-sm>
            <ion-col col-6 text-center>
              Generation
              <img id="generation" src="../../assets/img/solar-panel.png">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6 text-center>
              Grid
              <img id="grid" src="../../assets/img/grid.png">
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row responsive-sm>
            <img id="inverter" src="../../assets/img/logo.png">
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row responsive-sm>
            <ion-col col-6 text-center>
              Battery
              <img id="battery" src="../../assets/img/battery.png">
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6 text-center>
              Consumption
              <img id="consumption" src="../../assets/img/house.png">
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{description}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>





public drawGraphs (center:string, a:string, b:string, c:string, d:string){
    var canvas: any = document.getElementById("connection-canvas");
    var connectionGraph: any = document.getElementById("container-graph");
    canvas.width = connectionGraph.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = connectionGraph.clientHeight;
    var elCenter = document.getElementById(center);
    var contCenter = elCenter.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elA = document.getElementById(a);
    this.drawLine(elCenter,elA);
    var elB = document.getElementById(b);
    this.drawLine(elCenter,elB);
    var elC = document.getElementById(c);
    this.drawLine(elCenter,elC);
    var elD = document.getElementById(d);
    this.drawLine(elCenter,elD);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a viable solution. I call the function "drawgraphs" **after the view is completely renderized** by using the lifecycle hook interface **ngAfterViewChecked**.
[More info](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this.drawGraphs("inverter", "generation", "grid", "battery", "consumption")}
```